# Gaining Hjerim with a peace treaty

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to gain Hjerim if you negotiate a peace treaty in the "Season Unending" quest without taking sides?  The wiki says that in order to gain Hjerim, you must complete certain quests for either side of the civil war (either the Fort Neugrad mission or the Defeat the Stormcloaks mission).  However, if those quests never occur, can you still become Thane of Windhelm and gain Hjerim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The peace treaty is only until the dragon threat is dealt with, you will be able to complete either the Imperial Legion or the Stormcloaks storyline after completing the main quest, and Hjerim will be available as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Gaining the Hjerim is easy though. You can do that but you NEED the do the quest "Blood on Ice?" I think thats what you call it. This house is very glitchy and if you do not finish this quest properly then the murderer will still be in your house, and he can take things. He also cannot be killed.